# Placing feedback loop parts on PCB

Tags: power-supply, power, pcb, pcb-design, switch-mode-power-supply

I have one PCB for control circuitry and another for power parts (input caps, transformer, full bridge, output caps...).

I would like to ask if I can place some feedback parts (red square at picture) directly on "power board". Why I wanna do that? Since 10k resistor provides DC offset and there are 200V on the output and I don't want to use cables with higher dielectric insulation. Is that ok?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the effect of stray capacitance to the feedback (summing) node.

200V is hardly a burden (what, normal hookup wire is rated 300V?), and introducing noise to the summing node is probably a bad idea.  The resistors could be divided up, but with the lead-lag network on there too, that's awkward.

(Is this for voltage or current mode? If you're changing to current mode, you should find the lead-lag network isn't necessary anymore.)

Comment: ok thanks, this is for voltage mode =)